# Does an integral of a polar function from $0$ to infinity have to diverge?

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

This is more of a theoretical question, but I was curious if a polar equation automatically diverges as it goes to infinity? After all, the area will just be the area in the polar graph added to itself infinitely, right?

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you're asking now. If you want to integrate a function $f\colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$, then you can write $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac12 r^2(\theta) d\theta$. You're asking if $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac12 r^2(\theta) d\theta=\infty$. Well unless $r=0$ then yes of course. You're adding up a positive number infinitely many times. You are correct.

Comment: I does not agree ( see my answer), but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

No. $$\int 0 = 0$$ no matter of the domain.

Comment: 0 is a polar function. Here we integrate it, and it converges. Thus, unless you edit your question and acutally add some more concrete integral or exclude trivial counterexamples, this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your integral to have the meaning of an area, then you should not integrate the polar function itself but its square:

$$\frac12\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}r(\phi)^2d\phi$$

Of course, if you decide to evaluate that integral over a larger interval then you are running around the origin multiple times. For a closed curve and an integration interval that spans an integer multiple of $2\pi$ the integral would be the same integer multiple of the original area.

Comment: This is not specific for polar functions of closed curves: any integral of a periodic positive function becomes infinite. On the other hand, if you define a non-closed curve that spirals to the origin sufficiently quickly then the integral might be finite.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

I'm not sure to interpret correctly your question, but, for $r=e^{-\theta^2}$ we have:

$$
\int_0^\infty r d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$
and also

$$
\int_0^\infty r^2 d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$

Comment: In this case when $\theta$ goes to infinity the graph does not loop, but it is spiraling toward the origin in such a fast way that the area remain finite.